# How to validate input field value as plural word in laravel?

Tags: php, string, laravel

I want to store database table names in one database table. As per common convention, table names are plural and model are singular in Laravel.

I just want to validate if user input is plural or not.

For eg.

```
child => false, children => true
baby => false, babies => true
number => false, numbers => true,
```

Is there any library in php or laravel to check such property of the string ?

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the string helper functions for this, and compare it. So you can create your own [validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules) maybe. But here is the usage:

```
str_plural('child'); // = children

// or
Str::plural('child');
```

More on this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-plural).

Comment: I know about custom validation rule, Let me check the function

Comment: Thanks Man, Saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [custom rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules) which just checks if the given value equals it's pluralised form:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class IsPluralRule implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return $value === Str::plural($value);
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return ':attribute needs to be a plural!';
    }
}
```